# Adding /? switch in batch?

Tags: batch-file

Do someone knows how to add the action to be triggered when calling my batch file with the **/?** argument ? I've always used the **-h** to display usages, but for once I need my **-h** arg for something else.

EDIT : Actually I've tried by parsing attributes like this

```
for %%i in (%*) do ....
```

But the **/?** argument was skipped, I'll try yours solutions to see if it's different.

Btw, why when you parse **%%i** the **/?** args is skipped ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `/?` seems to be simply skipped by the `for %%i in (%*)` but it's the wildcard functionality of the for-loop, it tries to find a file that matches `/?` which will fail.

You can not use `?` or `*` in a "normal" for-loop, without modifying the result.

You could use the `SHIFT` command to access all your parameters.

```
:parameterLoop
if "%~1"=="/?" call :help
if "%~1"=="-h" call :help
if "%~1"=="-o" call :other
shift
if not "%~1"=="" goto :parameterLoop
```

If you also want to display the selected option, you got a problem with the echo command, as this will normally show the help instead of `/?`.

You can avoid this by using `echo(%1` instead of `echo %1`.

Answer (score 3):

You check your command line arguments (%1, %2 etc) against the /? string and if true then print help using `ECHO` command. For example,

```
@ECHO OFF
IF "%1"=="/?" (
    ECHO "Help Line 1"
    ECHO "Help Line 2"
) ELSE (
    ECHO "Do Your Action"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="/?" goto print_help
goto normal_start

:print_help
echo Here is your help
goto end

:normal_start
echo I'm working

:end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an actual use case for those visuals out there!

```
@ECHO OFF

:parameterLoop
IF /I "%1"=="/install" GOTO install
IF /I "%1"=="/uninstall" GOTO uninstall
IF /I "%1"=="/repair" GOTO repair
IF /I "%1"=="" (
    ECHO.
    ECHO Please use the following commands to proceed:
    ECHO.
    ECHO Use /INSTALL to setup the software
    ECHO.
    ECHO Use /UNINSTALL to remove the software
    ECHO.
    ECHO Use /REPAIR to repair the software
    ECHO.
    GOTO end
)

:install
TASKKILL /F /IM vpnui* /T
TASKKILL /F /IM DartOffline* /T
MSIEXEC /I "anyconnect-win-XXX-core-vpn-predeploy-k9.msi" /QN /NORESTART
MSIEXEC /I "anyconnect-win-XXX-dart-predeploy-k9.msi" /QN /NORESTART
MSIEXEC /I "anyconnect-win-XXX-posture-predeploy-k9.msi" /QN /NORESTART
COPY /Y "production.xml" "%ProgramData%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\Profile\production.xml"
GOTO end

:uninstall
TASKKILL /F /IM vpnui* /T
TASKKILL /F /IM DartOffline* /T
DEL /F /S /Q "%ProgramData%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\Profile\production.xml"
MSIEXEC /X "anyconnect-win-XXX-core-vpn-predeploy-k9.msi" /QN /NORESTART
MSIEXEC /X "anyconnect-win-XXX-dart-predeploy-k9.msi" /QN /NORESTART
MSIEXEC /X "anyconnect-win-XXX-posture-predeploy-k9.msi" /QN /NORESTART
RMDIR /S /Q "%ProgramData%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client"
GOTO end

:repair
TASKKILL /F /IM vpnui* /T
TASKKILL /F /IM DartOffline* /T
DEL /F /S /Q "%ProgramData%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\Profile\production.xml"
MSIEXEC /X "anyconnect-win-XXX-core-vpn-predeploy-k9.msi" /QN /NORESTART
MSIEXEC /X "anyconnect-win-XXX-dart-predeploy-k9.msi" /QN /NORESTART
MSIEXEC /X "anyconnect-win-XXX-posture-predeploy-k9.msi" /QN /NORESTART
RMDIR /S /Q "%ProgramData%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client"
MSIEXEC /I "anyconnect-win-XXX-core-vpn-predeploy-k9.msi" /QN /NORESTART
MSIEXEC /I "anyconnect-win-XXX-dart-predeploy-k9.msi" /QN /NORESTART
MSIEXEC /I "anyconnect-win-XXX-posture-predeploy-k9.msi" /QN /NORESTART
COPY /Y "production.xml" "%ProgramData%\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\Profile\production.xml"
GOTO end

:end 
EXIT /B

REM Src https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8179425/adding-switch-in-batch
```

Essentially with that command I can install my software using the /install or /uninstall or /repair switches... way useful in intune and making custom MSI's with AdvancedInstaller!

Also if you type nothing a little help menu appears instructing the user which commands are available :)